# R split string for each row

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` like

```
word | count
-------------
a,b,c| 5
c,d  | 3
c,d,e| 10
```

I want to split strings for each row to get this:

```
word | count
-------------
a    | 5
b    | 5
c    | 5
c    | 3
d    | 3
c    | 10
d    | 10
e    | 10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'word', ',', 'long')
#   word count
#1:    a     5
#2:    b     5
#3:    c     5
#4:    c     3
#5:    d     3
#6:    c    10
#7:    d    10
#8:    e    10
```